# How does URL shorteners process the code after the domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-shortener

I'm trying to create a URL shortener service. Most URL shortener services have use a code following the domain. For example, http://bit.ly/duSk8wK, duSk8wK would be the code. 
What code is needed in .htaccess file to make the server read the path part 'duSk8wK' and query in database, instead of going to the folder name /duSk8wK?

Comment: This is pretty broad, but I'd suggest that they have a data base of all those tokens and what the corresponding URL is, it then adapts that string into a GET variable with something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?token=$1`.

Comment: Ok, so an external PHP is needed for this to work? Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Well, no - not necessarily, bit.ly have a hell of a lot of functionality behind their service though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Htaccess, you could make a rewriterule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ redirect.php/?code=$1 [L]
```

Then in your `redirect.php`, you could simply get the code by using `$_GET["code"]`.

Comment: I edited your question to add a dot inside regex capture group , it prevents infinite loop error

Comment: @Starkeen Thanks for that, didn't see I missed it :p