# short url for parameter passing in either php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i see some websites is having a very simple URL without the GET value or something like this.

for instance `www.test.com/12345`

the 12345 is the ID of an item. i am sure that ID will be pass to back end or j query for processing such as fetch from db etc. But i am not sure in what way i need to use to get the ID in the URL in such simple format instead of the old way

`www.test.com/index.php?id=12345`

can someone guide me on this. not sure which method to do this

Comment: Use .htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: Similar: [How does URL shorteners process the code after the domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855381/how-does-url-shorteners-process-the-code-after-the-domain)

Comment: just one question for that .htaccess. if i have multiple ones, i can add more than one in htaccess right?

Comment: It rewrites the back part [index.php?id=12345] to [12345]

Comment: i mean can i have more than one ? example 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ redirect.php/?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ secondredirect.php/?id=$1 [L]

Comment: Yup, it's possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142971/apache-multiple-rewrite-rules

Comment: thanks alot for helping